# Laravel Session Unset Not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created a session by using `Session::put('user', $user_details);`

So i need to unset this while logout i tried

```
1 . Session::flush();
2 . Session::forget('user', $user_details);
```

but both didnt worked. any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

It's simply:

```
session()->forget('user'); // using the global helper
// or
\Session::forget('user'); // using the facade
```

to forget a single key. To flush the entire session, it's:

```
session()->flush(); // using the global helper
// or
\Session::flush(); // using the facade
```